# How to count duplicates in a row PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a usage database that i use to store some info whenever a user logs in.

So for each login the following is stored

- rid (auto integer)
- id (auto integer from the users database where the users details are stored login, contact details ect.)
- username
- password
- date (y-m-d)

Is there a way to count the number of times that a duplicate id appears in the database and ORDER by DESC.

What I want is to tell who is the most active user by counting how many times the same id appears in the database.

Comment: use `Group by` to count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query (as Tal Gleicher provided an errorous one, good thinking though):

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) as login_count FROM `tbl` 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY login_count DESC
```

You can set a limit for that query, for example if you want to get top 10 most active users' ids:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) as login_count FROM `tbl` 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY login_count DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id ,COUNT(*) 
FROM usageTable
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

This will display a list:

### id   | COUNT(*)

10   | 203
2    | 100
5    | 83

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -> SELECT count(rid) FROM `tbl` ORDER BY rid DESC GROUP BY id
```

It will show you the number of activities for each id